# PHP namespace best practice during refactoring?

Tags: php, namespaces

In C# and java world, we are used to have the namespace exactly map to the folder structure, and usually with com.myCompany as the prefix.
Now I start to work with a PHP project refactoring task:

- The project does not use namespace before.
- It does not have naming conflicts by using long class names with prefixes/suffixes.
- We use spl_autoload_register and it's simply search for files under pre-defined folders.
- Except for some modules, we do not plan to share the complete source code to public for reuse.
- the most IMPORTANT: we have limited resources to do refactoring.

Here are my questions:

1. should I use namespace for all the project files, or only use for
   those we want to public, or not use at all?
2. if use namespace, should it mapping the folder structure strictly (so can use autoload in a easier way), or a casual style is OK?
3. should I use com/myCompany as the prefix or not?
4. if there is any nice tool to do such safe refactoring? (I'm use PHPStorm but it cannot find all the usages as some code are
   dynamic.)

I would like to balance the best approach and the time required for refactoring. Appreciate your help in advanced.

P.S. I have read the https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md . If I do a new PHP project, I would definitely follow the guideline. However, I'm working with a existing projects, so I would like to know if the benefits I will gain from using namespace in strictly way, would be greater than the cost I spend; if there is any tradeoff I could make, to minimize the  changes I need to do.

Comment: I know this is an old post, but I'd highly recommend PHPStorm if you're doing refactoring - it will allow you to namespace a class and it will move the class to the correct folder and update any references to that class with the namespace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will make your life easier if you restructure your files to match the PSR-0 standard. Note that the standard does not force you to use namespaces. If you know the location of a file based on the classname, loading will be faster than if you need to search for the file.

Namespaces might make coding life a little bit easier, because class names are shorter. And you will avoid any name conflicts with your classes if you import any other external code (there are lots of useful libraries). But they are not the ultimate silver bullet, so you can live without them if you think it would be a waste of time.

Comment: Talking about shorter name, I found an interesting article here http://brady.lucidgene.com/2012/04/how-to-create-good-namespaces-and-class-names-in-php-5-3/ It shows shorter is not always the better:) So I wonder if I really need to add namespaces like /com/myCompany/proj/controller and rename the class ABCController to ABC. Seems not gain much from it.

Answer (score 1):

1-3) Just follow PSR-0 https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md
4) If PHPStorm can't find usages, then nobody else will :) PHPStorm has "Move class" refactoring which is very useful for this.

Answer (score 0):

Read about PSR (especially PSR-0 is on namespacing). They have a bunch of good coding standards.

https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md

Can't help you with your fourth question, though